# VSCode: Hide PowerShell method signature box

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

In the VSCode PowerShell extension I'd like to hide the box displaying the method signatures, see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2McXH.png).

Is this possible at all? If so, what's the name of the setting?

Otherwise, is it possible to move it out of the way? I often find myself trying to look at some code a line or two above only to be blocked by that window popping up.

Comment: You could hit `Esc`

Comment: Which I'd need to do constantly for every parameter I'm adding. I'm looking for a way to disable it from showing up completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

You can configure it in the settings (`ctrl + P`: Type `settings`). I think, adjusting the `"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay"` should do.

`"editor.parameterHints"` looks good, too